# How to add content to the index page using Flask-Admin

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I am using flask-admin, and I want to add a dashboard to the home page.  I found I can add a new page using:

```
admin = Admin(name='Dashboard', base_template='admin/my_master.html', template_mode='bootstrap3')
```

then:

```
admin.init_app(app)
```

and finally I added my_master.html, and added content.  However, it is all static, how can I add custom data to that view?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer in the documentation: http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_base/

It can be overridden by passing your own view class to the Admin constructor:

```
class MyHomeView(AdminIndexView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        arg1 = 'Hello'
        return self.render('admin/myhome.html', arg1=arg1)

admin = Admin(index_view=MyHomeView())
```

Also, you can change the root url from /admin to / with the following:

```
admin = Admin(
    app,
    index_view=AdminIndexView(
        name='Home',
        template='admin/myhome.html',
        url='/'
    )
)
```

Default values for the index page are:

- If a name is not provided, ‘Home’ will be used.
- If an endpoint is not provided, will default to admin Default URL route is /admin.
- Automatically associates with static folder. Default template is admin/index.html

Comment: also xhr/ajax might be the best solution for your project if you are reading this.  I found that to be another option that worked well for my dashboard.

Comment: Hi @nycynik... i am trying to override default page of airflow.. where are you getting the app object to pass in Admin constructor ?
I have posted a question as well here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864142/override-airflows-default-admin-index-page

Comment: The app is the Flask app `Parameters: app – Flask application instance` when you first init your Flask app, it returns the app instance.

Comment: app instance is already created when airflow starts... i am trying to override the default admin index page..so i will need the same app instance which was created at the starting... So not sure how to get that same app instance

Comment: Create your own template in "templates" folder, extend it like {% extends 'admin/master.html' %} then return self.render('mytemplate.html'), but nice to see this shorter way.

Answer (score 2):

According to [flask-admin documentation](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction/#adding-your-own-views) use this:

```
from flask_admin import BaseView, expose

class AnalyticsView(BaseView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        return self.render('analytics_index.html', args=args)

admin.add_view(AnalyticsView(name='Analytics', endpoint='analytics'))
```